# Contact Form 7 Event Triggers - Invalid not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-events

I am trying to use event triggers for contact form 7 and the submit works fine however the invalid isn't working or any of the others. I had it working for a few minutes and then it quit working - I don't know why.

Any ideas no how to get these events firing?

**Note:** I noticed that this is posting to the same page (or appears to be) at the same URL with a #wpcf7-f49-p43-o1 appended. I wonder if it isn't working because it is posting and a new page is being loaded that I never see my message but the code is actually executing? From my understanding alerts pause the code till the user acknowledges them though? Thoughts on that?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* ===========================================
   Contact Form 7
   Database Logic will make ajax posts to php script
   Post to URL's
   CUSTOM EVENT TRIGGERS:
   invalid.wpcf7, spam.wpcf7, mailsent.wpcf7, mailfailed.wpcf7, submit.wpcf7
   =========================================== */

  console.log('4');

  $(document).on('submit.wpcf7', function() {
    alert('submit.wpcf7 was triggered!');
  });

  $(document).on('spam.wpcf7', function() {
    alert('submit.wpcf7 was triggered!'); // Works
  });

  $(document).on('invalid.wpcf7', function() {
    alert('invalid.wpcf7 was triggered!');
  });

  $(document).on('mailsent.wpcf7', function() {
    alert('mailsent.wpcf7 was triggered!');
  });

  $(document).on('mailfailed.wpcf7', function() {
    alert('mailfailed.wpcf7 was triggered!');
  });
});
```

Comment: You're notion about `alert()` blocking the browser from continuing is true.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you figure anything out?